# shell-mode C-c C-c kill keybinding

Tags: osx, shell, comint

With some regularity, I am using bash with `M-x shell`, and out of muscle memory I hit `C-c C-c`, with dramatic results:

- the `comint` prompt streams a long error message with a large number of escaped characters;
- several files are created in the working directory with only escaped characters in the name.

Is there any way to send a kill signal to the prompt from within `comint-mode`, similar to what is triggered in a normal bash terminal with `C-c C-c`?

Edit: this is in Emacs for OS X Modified, and it only happens sometimes when I press `C-c C-c` in `shell-mode`

Comment: This isn't normal. `C-c C-c` in shell-mode sends `comint-interrupt-subjob`, which does the same thing as `C-c` in a standard shell. I can confirm this on vanilla Emacs (started via `emacs -Q`), none of the behaviours you describe occur. I suspect it may be due to the particular program you are trying to interrupt doing something strange. First thing to check: start emacs with `emacs -Q` and see if you can reproduce the problem. If you can't, the problem is in your init file.

Comment: @Tyler thanks for the suggestions. It happens sporadically enough that I can't reliably reproduce it, but I'm now pretty confident it's a combination of ZSH, $TERM / $SHELL, and color codes...well outside the realm of shell-mode's responsibility.